# a simple .net website source control system?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, version-control

I work in Visual Studio working on sites mostly myself and occasionally I start on new features for a site and bam a bug pops up on the live site and now I am in the middle of changes and can't post a fix to the bug until everything I started to change is complete.

So I am looking for a nice an simple way to work with this type of situation - any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you asking for a recommendation of a source control system? SourceGear Vault is [free for single users](http://www.sourcegear.com/faq.html#singleuser).

Comment: Vault rocks we use the heck out of it at my company

Comment: Vault. Good stuff! Definately try the single user.

Answer (score 4):

I am big fan of subversion.  There also plugins for VS to work with subversion repository.

http://subversion.tigris.org/
http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

Answer (score 1):

I am in a similar situation and I use [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/). It is free for up to two users and integrates well with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion is well supported and has tools for most any environment. It's also mostly straightforward to use, so you should be able to get up and running quickly.

If you need to work on a lot of separate features and bugs at the same time, you might try Mercurial instead. The tooling support is a lot less mature but I find the distributed design to do a better job of merging and facilitating work on separate issues concurrently.

But really, if you aren't using anything currently and aren't sure what your needs are, just choose one that has support in the IDE/tools you use. It will probably be Subversion.